# Web-based XMPP client with OTR support

Tags: web-apps, hosted, xmpp

Where I currently live and work there are restrictions on some protocols such as XMPP, so I can't use Pidgin or similar software anymore.

What is a reliable, web-based alternative to Pidgin that supports [OTR](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/)?

Note: I am **not** looking for a self-hosted client.

OTR is not the only requirement but the most important one for me at the moment. I'll take any other XMPP extension as a bonus. Encrypted voice and video chat would be greatly appreciated but not essential, text chat being the primary function of the app.

Comment: Related question for services that don’t necessarily have OTR support: [Web-based XMPP client (for any Jabber ID)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17197/60)

Answer (score 2):

https://conversejs.org/ supports OTR

This is available on their page or to include in your own webpage.

Comment: What exactly did you like about it, and what did you not like as much? How does the software match each requirement in the question? Thanks!