# Web-based XMPP client (for any Jabber ID)

Tags: web-apps, xmpp, hosted

I need a Web-based XMPP client that can be used with any Jabber ID.

Ideally without having to create a user account on the website, so

1. let me directly login with my existing JID and password,
2. show my roster, any offline messages, let me chat,
3. let me log out,
4. done.

I don’t need support for anything else, so no need for status messages, chat history, file transfer, Jingle, MUC etc.

Related questions:

- [Web-based XMPP client with **OTR** support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14443/60)
- [Web-based XMPP client for **self-hosting**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2383/60)

Answer (score 3):

https://conversejs.org/ can be used for this.

It supports logging into any public jabber using a httpbind protocol either on their page or you can integrate the chat into your web page.

It even supports OTR.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work great for chatting (and even registering new JIDs!), but I didn’t manage to receive offline messages (don’t know if the issue is with Converse.js or my accounts, though).

Comment: I think I was able to receive offline message with conversejs